# iOS9 Developer Trust App No Internet Connection Error

Tags: ios, iphone, ios9

I am using Xcode 7 and iOS 9. I'm having trouble in launching my app on my device using the new feature that Xcode 7 has, that allows us to try applications without having an Apple Developer Program

Here's what I get from Profile when I try to trust and verify apps. It keeps telling me that I need to connect to the internet but I'm always connected. I try to delete my profile and my app and restarting my phone but it doesn't work.

Any suggestions?

[Error1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lsdl6.png)

[Error2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BGA0E.png)

Comment: My iPad is running iOS 9.3.2 and I'm having the same issue.  All of my apps have internet access, but Settings refuses to let me Verify my company's certificate, saying that there's no internet access....  Restarting my iPad made no difference.

Comment: I have this problem right now in 2018 August and September, and the problem is not that the https://ppq.apple.com/ would be down, but it's SSL certificate is not considered valid any more. What to do now?

Comment: FWIW - I was having this same issue and it was related to the firewall settings on my wifi router.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I'm currently having this problem right now too, Cellular, and quitting Settings didn't help.

This article (https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT204460) mentions you need to be able to connect to http://ppq.apple.com to verify the app.  As of right now (Dec 4th, 2015), it seems to be down.

"An Internet connection is required to verify the app developer's certificate when establishing trust. If you're behind a firewall, make sure it's configured to allow connections to https://ppq.apple.com. If you aren't connected to the Internet when you trust an app, the device displays "Not Verified" instead. In order to use the app, you need to connect to the Internet, and tap the Verify App button."

So I assume if that site is down, you can't trust apps.

Comment: Came back up in a few minutes and was able to verify the app again.  Try this: http://downforeveryoneorjustme.com/ppq.apple.com

Comment: it is down right now as well. My team leads are making the same noises

Comment: Yes verifying it on my end as well, it seem apple's verification service is down

Answer (score 15):

I had the same issue. I tried to switch between WIFI and Cellular data but no results. I was testing on iPad Pro with ios 9.3.2 and I even updated it to the latest software update available which is 9.3.3.

Again the efforts were in vain! I still got the error message "No Internet Connection Error".

Then I noticed my Timezone and DataTime was different and when I set it to "Set Automatically", VOILA ! Afterwards, I could trust the developer and verify app successfully.

So make sure, you set the DATE TIME and TIMEZONE correctly while you trust a developer and verify apps.

Comment: I had a similar issue, but I first had to turn off 'Set Automatically', pick a Timezone, and then turn it back on

Answer (score 8):

Something has changed in the last day.  Not sure if it's a Apple verification server issue or WiFi issue with iOS 9.0.2.

Anyway, the workaround is this.  We have clients doing this today.

1. Disconnect from WiFi and connect via cellular.  You may have to hotspot to a phone if your iPad is WiFi only.
2. Clear the Settings iOS app out of memory.
3. Re-launch the Settings app and go to Profiles.
4. Click Verify link again and should verify / work.

Comment: Worked for me, tnx

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me. Stop debugging. Close Settings app (double tap on home and swipe up). Open Settings app again and got to `General>Device Management>Select the app certificate> trust`. This works

Comment: Yes, device needs to be connected to internet.

Comment: General>Device Management>Select the app certificate> trust

Answer (score 0):

this happens when the phone has no wifi or 3G/4G signal. You may have run out of minutes on your data plan for example or disabled your wifi etc.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem was that I was using a VPN (Charles proxy) and I forgot about it. Just turned off the VPN, accepted the profile, and switch the VPN on.

Answer (score 0):

As of iOS 13.1.3, this now seems to be the message received when your distribution certificate is revoked.  It used to just appear to force quit the app, but now it displays this message and refuses to verify.  Rebuilding the app with a current certificate should fix it in this case.

Answer (score 0):

For me, my iPhone was not connected to Wi-Fi. After I have the iPhone Wi-Fi connected, I could build and install.